# why cannot an emulator send email in android

Tags: android, email, android-emulator

i looking for code to send an email from my android application. I have googled and read that the code that are given will not run on emulators. i will have to put the code on actual devices to send an email. 
why is this so?

thank you in advance

Comment: do you have a link to this code?

Comment: We can send email successfully via emulator. please refer
 [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6978877/how-can-i-configure-gmail-in-android-emulator][1]
 

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6978877/how-can-i-configure-gmail-in-android-emulator

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This migh be helpful [Android Email Intent](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-email-intent/)

> If you are using an emulator, you’ll
>   need to configure the email client. If
>   the email client is not configured, it
>   will not respond to the Intent we’ll
>   be discussing. If you want to see the
>   chooser in action, you’ll need to
>   configure a device using multiple
>   messaging applications, such as the
>   Gmail application and the Email
>   application.

But using a phone might be way better and easy for sure.

Comment: Of course, an actual device would work easier. But some of us don't have one. Your post begs the question: How do I configure an email client to work with the emulator?

Comment: Yes could you please tell me how to configure the email client inside the emulator?

Answer (score 2):

Because the emulator does not have an email app. You'll have to install one.

Answer (score 2):

As the previous answers said, the emulator doesn't include any email application for security purposes. Nonetheless you can download one (k9mail, for example) and it will work without issues whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

Because emulator is our virtual device is use only for testing purpose.
 and reason is emulator is not a valid IP address due to security purpose it is not send email by emulator.