# Cannot send mail through emulator

Tags: android

I am getting following exception on log cat while sending mail.

```
01-13 14:32:36.559: DEBUG/SntpClient(68): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
01-13 14:34:41.831: WARN/System.err(1753): javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465;
01-13 14:34:41.831: WARN/System.err(1753):   nested exception is:
01-13 14:34:41.839: WARN/System.err(1753):     java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connection timed out
01-13 14:34:41.839: WARN/System.err(1753):     at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1391)
01-13 14:34:41.839: WARN/System.err(1753):     at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:412)
01-13 14:34:41.849: WARN/System.err(1753):     at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:288)
01-13 14:34:41.849: WARN/System.err(1753):     at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:169)
01-13 14:34:41.849: WARN/System.err(1753):     at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:118)
01-13 14:34:41.849: WARN/System.err(1753):     at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:188)
01-13 14:34:41.859: WARN/System.err(1753):     at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:118)
01-13 14:34:41.859: WARN/System.err(1753):     at com.enthrall.GMailSender.sendMail(GMailSender.java:75)
01-13 14:34:41.859: WARN/System.err(1753):     at com.enthrall.MailSenderActivityActivity$1.onClick(MailSenderActivityActivity.java:24)
01-13 14:34:41.869: WARN/System.err(1753):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
01-13 14:34:41.869: WARN/System.err(1753):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
01-13 14:34:41.869: WARN/System.err(1753):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
01-13 14:34:41.869: WARN/System.err(1753):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-13 14:34:41.869: WARN/System.err(1753):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-13 14:34:41.879: WARN/System.err(1753):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
01-13 14:34:41.879: WARN/System.err(1753):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-13 14:34:41.879: WARN/System.err(1753):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-13 14:34:41.879: WARN/System.err(1753):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-13 14:34:41.879: WARN/System.err(1753):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-13 14:34:41.899: WARN/System.err(1753):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-13 14:34:41.899: WARN/System.err(1753): Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connection timed out
01-13 14:34:41.899: WARN/System.err(1753):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.connect(Native Method)
01-13 14:34:41.909: WARN/System.err(1753):     at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedNetworkSystem.connect(BlockGuard.java:357)
01-13 14:34:41.909: WARN/System.err(1753):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:204)
01-13 14:34:41.909: WARN/System.err(1753):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:437)
01-13 14:34:41.909: WARN/System.err(1753):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:983)
01-13 14:34:41.919: WARN/System.err(1753):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:926)
01-13 14:34:41.919: WARN/System.err(1753):     at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:233)
01-13 14:34:41.919: WARN/System.err(1753):     at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:163)
01-13 14:34:41.919: WARN/System.err(1753):     at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1359)
01-13 14:34:41.919: WARN/System.err(1753):     ... 19 more
01-13 14:37:36.589: DEBUG/SntpClient(68): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
01-13 14:41:02.749: INFO/dalvikvm(68): Jit: resizing JitTable from 4096 to 8192
```

This is the properties i have set and i have also mentioned Internet permission in manifest file. What sholud i change so that mail can be sent through emulator

```
 Properties props = new Properties();    
    props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");    
    props.setProperty("mail.host", mailhost);    
    //props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");    
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");  

    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");    
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",    
            "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");    
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");    
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");    

    session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);
```

Comment: This link may help you (if you haven't already refred) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042487/why-cannot-an-emulator-send-email-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Have you given Internet Permission in your app?

```
android.permission.INTERNET
```

Comment: yes i have written android.permission.INTERNET in manifest file.Still it is giving same exception.. :(