# Can not send email through android emulator

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I want to send email using my app from android emulator. but the problem is I recieve a FORCE CLOSE error. I can browse Internet on emulator. What do I do ? Here is the errors shown in console window

"    [2012-08-06 09:43:11 - Unexpected error while launching logcat. Try reselecting the     device.] device not found
    com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: device not found
        at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.setDevice(AdbHelper.java:752)
        at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:373)
         at com.android.ddmlib.Device.executeShellCommand(Device.java:462)
        at com.android.ddmuilib.logcat.LogCatReceiver$1.run(LogCatReceiver.java:109)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
"

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to configure the email client -- See [why cannot an emulator send email in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042487/why-cannot-an-emulator-send-email-in-android) for more information.

Comment: I figured the solution for this error but now the problem is when I click on send button, k9 app starts and in there, there is no option for sending the email. What should I do now

Answer (score 0):

Android emulator does not contain any e-mail client for security purpose that's why android application is not be able to send mail via emulator, But it works fine in Android Real Device, try to install your application in real device and check it. Do not forgot to give "INTERNET" permission to your manifest file.